# Rails 4: Modify eager load query when using .includes(:association)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :purchases

  # Perform joins and attach some calculations to the User object
  scope :add_stats, -> { group("users.id").joins(:purchases).select("users.*, SUM(purchases.price) AS total_purchases") }
end

class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

The `add_stats` scope represents heavy calculations attached to the `User` objects. So if I want to get all `User` objects with stats, I just write `User.all.add_stats`.

So far so good. Now I want to fetch some `Purchase` objects and eager load the `User`s **with stats** as well. I've tried this:

`belongs_to :user, -> { add_stats }`

But then when Rails eager load the users, it seems to remove `.group("user.id").joins(:purchases)` and complain on `purchases.price` - "purchases table unknown". So the `.select()` is the only thing preserved from the scope.

**How do I apply a scope (with working `.group().joins()`) to the eager load query of all included `belongs_to :user` objects?**

Answer (score 0):

i just tried it in my rails4 app and it works

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :add_stats, -> { group("users.id").joins(:events).select("users.*, SUM(events.id) AS total_events") }

class Event
  belongs_to :user, -> { add_stats }
```

in rails console

```
Event.includes(:users).first.user.total_events
Reloading...
  Event Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."label" = 'hamburg' ORDER BY "events"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Participant Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "participants".* FROM "participants" WHERE "participants"."event_id" IN (2)
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20)
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT users.*, SUM(events.id) AS total_events FROM "users" INNER JOIN "events" ON "events"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE "users"."id" = ? GROUP BY users.id ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
=> 68

Event.first.user.total_events
Reloading...
  Event Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."label" = 'hamburg' ORDER BY "events"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT users.*, SUM(events.id) AS total_events FROM "users" INNER JOIN "events" ON "events"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE "users"."id" = ? GROUP BY users.id ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
=> 68
```

i guess that this is not what you want, as this does not use the scope for the include.

Comment: Sorry, this still has the 1+N problem which is what I'm trying to solve.

Comment: @thejaz it's really unpleasant to be downvoted. keep in mind that people actually try to help you. as i already said in the answer, this is probably not what you want. it just shows that it is possible to use the scope. if you have any error, it's due to an error in your code.

Comment: not to mention it drives away people who may be interested in helping out.

Comment: @Nikola yeah, i am 100% not helping on this question any longer, even though i could provide a lot of information. ie that using a `select *` with a `group` is a feature of only a few databases. oracle in example wont allow that. you can just query fields used for `sum`, `count` etc...

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted; worked fine for me. Thank you!